# jquery .animate different speeds

Tags: jquery, effects

I am using the .animate function in Jquery. I have a div that slides over using marginLeft, but I also need it to fade in, but I need it to be slower than the marginLeft effect. With .animate, I can only seem to apply one speed parameter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".topFrameAnim").css("opacity", "0.0");
  $(".topFrameAnim").animate({
  marginLeft: "0",
    }, 500 );

    $(".topFrameAnim").animate({
  opacity: "1",
    }, 1000 ); // Need this effect to be applied at the same time, at a different speed.




    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the two argument form of animate, with `queue:false` in the options array (on the first animation):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".topFrameAnim").css("opacity", "0.0")

 .animate({
  marginLeft: "0",
    }, { queue: false, duration: 500 })
  .animate({
  opacity: "1",
    }, 1000 ); // Need this effect to be applied at the same time, at a different speed.

    });


</script>
```

Note: It's .animate here to reduce the number of selectors used.  Since you're selecting the same objects, it's better to reuse the existing object.

Comment: I don't want to be an asshole, but for future noobs like me I just want to add that you are missing a curly brace. It should be like this...  }, { queue: false, duration: 500 } ).... Just for the heads up. Nice work btw!