# jQuery fx speeds are different speeds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is similar to another stack overflow post but it didn't answer my question [jquery .animate different speeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902027/jquery-animate-different-speeds)

Here is my js

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;

$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});

function social() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".info7").hide();
        $("#social_media").show("fade");
        $("#hide").show();
    });
}

function social_hide() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".info7").show();
        $("#social_media").hide("fade");
        $("#hide").hide();
    });
}

<!--
if (screen.width <= 800) {
    document.location = "iphone-website.php";
}
//-->

//tipsy popup code

$(function () {
    $('.info').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:"Use the different search engines to find what you're looking for, These search engines search leagucraft.com and mobafire.com for the information you need."});
    $('.info2').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:"Click this to open the search engine box in another window."});
    $('.info3').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:"You can put your user name here instead."});
    $('.info4').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:"League of Legends InfoMatic Blog."});
    $('.info5').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:"League of Legends InfoMatic Facebook page."});
    $('.info6').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:"This website is mobile browser friendly!"});
    $('.info7').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:"Click here to show the social media buttons."});
    $('.info8').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:"Click here to hide the social media buttons."});
});

function init() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").show("fade");
    });
}
```

and for some reason even if I put $.fx.speeds._default = 1000; behind every jquery function or w/e they are all still different speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations use timers to avoid blocking the UI and simulate "asynchronous events".

According to [J.Resig's post](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

> If a timer is blocked from immediately executing it will be delayed until the next possible point of execution (which will be longer than the desired delay).

Therefore, timers *are not exact*

Comment: so there is no way to make them all the same?

Comment: @TechbyTbone yes, if JS isn't busy processing a lot of things at the same time. But most likely it will, so that would be more like no.